# Computing $\mathbb{Q}[X] \cap I$ when $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Given the ideal $I=\langle X^2-Y,Y^2-X\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, I want to find generators of the ideal
$$\mathbb{Q}[X]\cap I$$ as an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Now, I know how this can be done using Gröbner bases, but I tried doing it a different way. Notice that in the quotient $$\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/I$$
We have $$[Y]=[X^2]$$ such that
$$\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/I\cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/\langle X^4-X\rangle$$
and this ideal $\langle X^4-X\rangle$ is exactly (up to a unit) the one you get using Gröbner bases, so it can't be a coincidence.

The inclusion $\langle X^4-X\rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[X]\cap I$ isn't hard to show, but I'm struggling with the other inclusion.